# Uso de attr para aplicar cor de borda em LI

Tags: jquery, css

Possuo uma `li`, que é um quadrado, o CSS está assim

```
.produtos{
    width: 294px;
    height: 349px;
    /*background-color: #f1f2f2;*/
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .4s ease-out;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

O que acontece, é que quero mudar o cor do `border` quando o usuário passar o mouse em cima.
Não posso fazer isso com o `hover` simples do CSS, pois essa cor será gerenciável. Já tenho uma palavra reservada que irá aplicar essa cor, só acho que o ideal seria usar um attr em Jquery, estou certo?

Meu HTML está assim:

```
<li data-cor="codigoSYS" style="background-image: url(fotoSYS&w=294)" class="produtosBorda produtos f-left margin-right-30 margin-top-30"></li>
```

**codigoSYS** é o valor hexadecimal da cor que é recebido pelo gerenciador.

Jquery:

```
var cor = $('.produtosBorda').attr('data-cor');
$('.produtosBorda').css('border-color', cor);
```

Comment: Tem como colocar um trecho do código html, o css e um exemplo de como ficaria o resultado final?, porque talvez tenha várias soluções ai se pode escolhe a melhor ao seu código!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não, use o método `.css()` em vez do `attr`. Por exemplo:

```
$('li').css('border-color', '#00ff00');
```

Se a cor vier de um data-attribute no seu HTML, não tem problema. Por exemplo:

```
<li id="sei-la" data-cor="#ff0000">...</li>
```

```
var cor = $('#sei-la').attr('data-cor');
$('#sei-la').css('border-color', cor);
```

---

Para reagir à entrada e saída do mouse em cada `<li>`, algo assim deve funcionar:

```
$('li.produtos').mouseenter(function() {
    var li = $(this);
    // guarda cor original num atributo
    li.attr('data-cor-original', li.css('border-color'));
    // define nova cor
    li.css('border-color', li.attr('data-cor'));
}).mouseleave(function() {
    var li = $(this);
    // restaura cor original
    li.css('border-color', li.attr('data-cor-original'));
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu gostaria de usar um `attr`, pois como eu comentei, essa cor será gerenciável pelo usuário. Por isso, eu não posso definir a cor da borda com com jquery, e sim no HTML. Acredito eu.

Comment: Você está falando de data-attributes? Atualizei minha resposta, veja se é isso.

Comment: Exatamente isso! Nota 10. Só tem duas coisas, que agradeceria se você pudesse me ajudar. Tenho uma listagem de elementos e ele está aplicando apenas no primeiro item. Segundo, ele tem como aplicar apensa no :hover?

Comment: Você está fazendo o hover por jquery, @FelipeStoker? O exemplo que dei usa um ID para escolher o li que será afetado, mas qualquer seletor funcionaria. Fica difícil dizer o que usar no seu caso sem ver mais do seu código. Você poderia atualizar a pergunta?

Comment: Oi, como é uma listagem de repetição, eu tirei o ID e coloquei na classe. Funfou, porém ele aplica a mesma cor para todos. Editei minha pergunta.

Comment: Editei a resposta novamente, @FelipeStoker

Comment: Cara, ficou PERFEITO! Muito obrigado!